# Scandinavian characters not working in go-lang go-instagram API bindings

Tags: go, instagram, instagram-api

Hi I'm trying to wrap my head around what seems to be a problem with multibyte support in this open source library (https://github.com/carbocation/go-instagram/). I am using the code below to retrieve information about the tag blue in swedish. How ever I get an empty array when trying.

```
fmt.Println("Starting instagram download.")
client := instagram.NewClient(nil)
client.ClientID = "myid"
media, _, _ := client.Tags.RecentMedia("blå", nil)
fmt.Println(media)
```

I have tried using the api trough the browser and there are several pictures tagged with the tag. I have also tried using the code snippet with tags in English like blue and that returns the latest pictures as well. I would be glad if any one could explain why this might happen. Id like to update the lib so it supports multi-byte but I haven't got the go knowledge required. Is this a go problem or a problem with the library?

Thank you

Comment: `RecentMedia()` returns an error as its last value; you're throwing that error away. What is the error?

Comment: I am going to check that. sorry for not checking Immediately.

Comment: I have now checked and there is no error returned. Just nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in [`validTagName()`](https://github.com/carbocation/go-instagram/blob/master/instagram/tags.go#L130-L143):

```
// Strip out things we know Instagram won't accept. For example, hyphens.
func validTagName(tagName string) (bool, error) {
    //\W matches any non-word character
    reg, err := regexp.Compile(`\W`)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    if reg.MatchString(tagName) {
        return false, nil
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

In Go, [`\W` matches precisely `[^0-9A-Za-z_]`](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). This validation check is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you that should be easily fixed then. Do you want to do the pull req or should I?

Comment: Go right ahead. I don't use this library and can't test the results. Personally I would remove this function entirely. Don't check "do I think Instagram will accept this." Just ask Instagram. If it won't accept it, you'll get an error.

Comment: I agree. Or if you check at least provide the default option of not checking.